# return selected field for drop down list

Tags: php, forms

I want if the user clicks submit to return the the selected value when the form reloads

that what I try and no luck

```
<?php
            $getData = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM first_university_degree_list");
            if ($getData->execute()) {
                $res = $getData->get_result();
                while ($data = $res->fetch_array()) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $data['univ_degree']; ?>" <?php if($FirstUniversityDegree == $data['univ_degree']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>><?php echo $data['univ_degree']; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

**clearing the question** 
I have a validation for every field on the form so if any of this fields return false the options on the drop menu will return to the first item
I need it to return on the selected item the users selected

Comment: you want to populate dropdown list with records form database,is it?

Comment: it's already populate ... no I need if the form reloads to return the users selected item

Comment: did you use javascript/jquery validation? If no, use it that will be return user selected value. else please give the javascript validation code.

Answer (score 0):

As far i understood your problem,i think this is the solution you are looking for,

```
<?php
    $getData = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM first_university_degree_list");
    if ($getData->execute()) {
        $res = $getData->get_result();
        while ($data = $res->fetch_array()) {
            if($FirstUniversityDegree == $data['univ_degree'])
            {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['univ_degree']; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $data['univ_degree']; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            else
            {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $data['univ_degree']; ?>" ><?php echo $data['univ_degree']; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>

        <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: thanks but still after submit the form it return as no items selected

Comment: where does the $FirstUniversityDegree  value come from?

Comment: it comes from database

Comment: this was working fine with me `<option
        value="6thof October University" <?php if ($FirstUniversityDegree == "6thof October University") echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>
        6thof October University
    </option>` but now I am planing to get the list from my database and the problem started

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
            $getData = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM first_university_degree_list");
            if ($getData->execute()) {
                $res = $getData->get_result();
                while ($data = $res->fetch_array()) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $data['univ_degree']?>" <?php if($FirstUniversityDegree==$data['univ_degree']) print 'selected="selected"'; ?>>
                        <?php echo $data['univ_degree']; ?></option>
                <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
```

hoe it helps